# Django - show images with src from python list

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to show few images on my website, I've collected the sources of all of them in a list. In html file I've created a loop to iterate through each of them.
HTML body :

```
<body>
<div class="content">
    {% for output in outputs %}
        <h1> {{ output }} </h1>
        <img src="{% static '{{output}}' %}" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%">
        <img src="{% static 'images/1.jpg' %}" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%">
    {% endfor %}
</div>
</body>
```

So, the thing is - I am able to show image "1.jpg" from "images" directory (so the problem is not due to static files). I've also checked that "output" has the right content. This is the output of my code :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfIoF.jpg)
And this is directory where I store my images :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2Efw.png)
please, let me know if you have any idea what should i do next. Any advise will be helpful.

Comment: Use `{% static output %}` not `{% static '{{output}}' %}` if you inspect the html you would see something like `src="/static/{{output}}"` for what you wrote..

Comment: You're absolutely right! thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

That's what worked for me, thanks to Abdul Aziz Barkat!
"Use {% static output %} not {% static '{{output}}' %} if you inspect the html you would see something like src="/static/{{output}}" for what you wrote.."